# NSLocalizedString weird warning

Tags: objective-c, localization, ios4, xcode4

I'm trying to localize my app in English and Italian.

I got this portion of code:

```
-(IBAction)randomSN{
int text = rand() % 2;
switch (text) {
    case 0:
        textview.text =NSLocalizedString(@"YES", @"Sì");
        break;
    case 1:
        textview.text = NSLocalizedString("@NO", @"No");
        break;
    default:
        break;
  }
}
```

When i go to Build and Run, some warnings come up:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'localizedStringForKey:value:table:' from incompatible pointer type
```

I think it says that it needs a table to work or? The warning is shown only on the second part, when it says

```
            textview.text = NSLocalizedString("@NO", @"No");
```

Also, when i run the project, with the simulator set on English (main language of the app is italian), what i typed into Localizable.strings doesn't appear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you have the `@` in the right place? It appears to me that it should be:

```
textview.text = NSLocalizedString(@"NO", @"No");
```

In other words, the `@` should come *before* the opening `"`.

Comment: Yes, that was my error.. Thanks a lot for this! By the way, any ideas why it doesn't work in simulator? I have an action,as you can see, that randomizes the words. I've inserted the translation into Localizable.strings (English) and (Italian),but it keeps showing the italian one.

Comment: Edit - Now it works, i had to check better the strings. thanks for the help!